# Concat fields in WHERE LIKE clause based on search string using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, sequelize.js, concatenation

I would like to know how to write query to search columns in different forms.

I have four columns, user can search by `12-2, SG Euro St` or `456667` or `1, 123 Cross St`
Like in any combinations

How to write query using Sequelize for multiple search combinations?
It works, but combination of list goes on

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
Article.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("concat", Sequelize.col("block"), '-',Sequelize.col("floor")), {
        like: '%12-2%'
    })
});
```

Output:

| ID | block | floor | street | pincode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2 | SG Euro St | 456667 |
| 2 | 14 | 10 | KR St | 234568 |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | 123 Cross St | 987670 |

Comment: Is it possible for you to accept user input for certain specific columns?

Comment: Maybe you need to look at full-text search by creating a certain index that will include all searchable columns and use special operators to search